# Time complexity of map with Vector as key and value (C++)

Tags: c++, time-complexity, unordered-map

I want to construct a map in C++, the key of the map I want to keep as vector.

```
map<vector<int>,int>>mp;
```

So, what would be the time complexity for inserting, searching and deleting the key in the map?

Also, what would be the difference in time complexity if I take unordered_map instead of map?

```
unordered_map<vector<int>,int>>mp;
```

Now , I construct another map , with vector as key and vector as value,
what would be the time complexity for insertion, deletion and searching in this scenario in case of map and unordered_map

```
map<vector<int>,vector<int>>mp;
unordered_map<vector<int>,vector<int>>mp;
```

Comment: Instead of wondering, find out. Test for various values of *N* entries per map, and *M* vector length. It's pretty quick to test if you increment by powers of 10 and will quickly see where it becomes impractical.

Comment: Complexity with respect to ***what***? With respect to a random key: same complexity as any other map or unordered map. With respect to the length of the vector key: that would be a different story...

Comment: There are just too many variables to come up with a easy formula here. E.g. it matters whether you're move-constructing key/value. Even whether the elements type of the value vector is trivially destructible can make a difference. As for `std::map` lookup it matters based on which measurement you want to analyze. There'll be `O(log(N))` (`N` being the number of elements in the map) comparisons and if all keys have length `M` the same length and contain the same elements except for the last one, lookup will be in `O(log(N) * M)`.

Comment: `unordered_map<vector<int>,vector<int>>` won't compile, as there's no `std::hash` implementation for an arbitrary vector (there's one for `std::vector<bool>`).

Comment: For `std::unordered_map`, if you're analyzing the worst case scenario, you get `O(M)` calculation of the hash and you've got all the keys being mapped to the same bucket with a fixed faction of the key elements being the same at the front for `O(M + N * M) = O(M*N)` worst case... The expected case should be in `O(M)` though...

Comment: Time complexity is a function of `N` where `N` is the size of something that's growing towards infinity. In your proposed data structure, what is growing - the number of elements in the map, the number of elements in each vector, both (and if so, how if at all are the two correlated)? When the C++ standard talks about "time complexity of inserting into a map", it means the number of key comparisons relative to the number of elements in the map. This definition doesn't depend on the type of the key. Apparently, you have a different measure in mind - you'll have to spell it out.

Answer (score 0):

> So, what would be the time complexity for inserting, searching and deleting the key in `map<vector<int>,int>>mp;`?

There are several distinct complexities at play here:

- all those operations on a map require O(logN) key comparisons where N is the number of elements in the map, and
- each of those comparisons can require up to V element comparisons where V is the size of two vectors being compared, so that's O(V) per comparison worst-case, and actually-equal keys always need that worst-case V comparisons

  - in some cases, you may know that for non-equal vectors, comparing the first few elements is overwhelmingly likely to reveal which is less than the other, such that the amortised average/typical comparison cost is O(1)
- if you're inserting a vector to the map, then if the vector is moveable it'll be an O(1) ownership transfer, but if it needs to be deep-copied that will be O(V)
- if you find the key you ask to erase, that'll be O(V) to invoke destructors unless the vector elements are trivially  destructible

The best way to wrap your head around this is to consider that big-O is used to describe how operations slow down as the size of *something* varies.  You could imagine a program where the number of entries in the map is constant, but the vector sizes vary, and you'll see quite a few O(V) operations.  You can also imagine having constant average vector size, but seeing the number of map elements grow, in which case the increase in average time per operation will be O(logN).

> Also, what would be the difference in time complexity if I take unordered_map instead of map?  i.e. `unordered_map<vector<int>,int>>mp;`

This differs in two ways:

- hash tables reduce the number of other vectors you typically have to compare with before you can find the key you're seeking, or know that it's not in the table, to a small constant (for reasonable load factors and hash functions)
- hash tables care about equality of keys, but not ordering, so if the hash value calculated from the vector contents is saved in the hash table (as e.g. GCC does), it can be compared first to quickly recognise the huge majority (again assuming a decent hash function) of cases where keys are unequal

> Now , I construct another map , with vector as key and vector as value, what would be the time complexity for insertion, deletion and searching in this scenario in case of map and unordered_map  `map<vector<int>,vector<int>>mp; unordered_map<vector<int>,vector<int>>mp;`

The difference during insertion is that you might need to move or copy the value into the hash table; if deep-copying there are complexities corresponding to the number of elements in the value vector, akin to what I've already explained for the key vector.

During searching, the values are not accessed and don't affect operational efficiency.

During erasing, if the containers store vector values and the elements aren't trivially destructible, then the efficiency of that is O(J) where J represents the lengths of the value vectors.

---

To try to give perspective on this, if you use a map and store say 1000 times as many key/value elements with similar-size vectors, individual insert/search/erase operations will tend to be log2of1000 ~= 10x slower.  If you instead use a hash table, they shouldn't be slower (ignoring, as we tend to do in big-O analysis, caching effects and memory limits).  But, either way, if you're using a map or an unordered map and you start storing key vectors that are 1000 times larger, most operations will risk being 1000x slower, though searching for keys not already in the container is often faster for hash tables because constant-time hash equality comparison avoids full vector-element comparison, and even for maps - some data sets will have a near-certainty of being resolved by comparing the first few elements in the vectors.  If you have value vectors and they become 1000x larger, then insertions, and successful erases of non-trivially-destructible values, will become about 1000x slower.